# Retrieve lyrics from genius package in r

Tags: r

I'm  trying to get lyrics from specific songs by using the package "genius" in R. I have used the functions from the package:

```
kendrick <- gen_song_url("Kendrick Lamar","Humble")
genius_url(kendrick, info = "all")
```

From "kendrick" I get the url for the lyric on genius webpage. But when I use the function genius_url I get this error message:

> Error in stream$next_ident() : Expected ident, got <EOF at 2>

Which I do not understand. Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: may be refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70413244/get-lyrics-from-song-with-geniusr

Comment: That code does not work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

A issue has been raised, here https://github.com/JosiahParry/genius/issues/62

If you need the lyrics you can use the `rvest` package

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

kendrick %>% read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes('.Lyrics__Container-sc-1ynbvzw-6') %>% 
  html_text()

[1] "[Intro]Nobody pray for meIt been that day for meWay (Yeah, yeah)[Verse 1]Ayy, I remember syrup sandwiches and crime allowancesFinesse a nigga with some counterfeits, but now I'm countin’ thisParmesan where my accountant lives, in fact I'm downin' thisD’USSÉ with my boo bae tastes like Kool-Aid for the analystsGirl, I can buy your ass the world with my paystubOoh, that pussy good, won't you sit it on my taste blood
```